# PHP JWT (JSON Web Token) com assinatura SSL RSA sem biblioteca

Tags: php, jwt, openssl, rsa

Alguém conhece alguma solução em PHP para usar JWT (JSON Web Token) com assinatura SSL RSA sem usar nenhuma biblioteca? Eu tentei tanto encontrar soluções sem biblioteca ou sem usar o composer. Mas não consegui encontrar nada somente com exemplos de codificação para implementar uma própria solução.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow **em português**. Tal como o nome sugere, o idioma oficial usado aqui é o português. Assim sendo, você poderia por favor traduzir sua pergunta? Caso prefira, você também pode fazer essa mesma pergunta no [site em inglês do Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @LeticiaRosa não sabia dessa diferenciação, sempre acessava em inglês. Mas vou fazer o que você falou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ATUALIZAÇÃO:** Eu fiz minha própria solução usando outros exemplos pelo caminho. Abaixo temos 3 casos de uso e os códigos PHPs específicos para quem deseja usar:

1. Crie chaves públicas e privadas RSA para assinar JWT usando a biblioteca openssl
2. Crie um token JWT e assine usando chaves privadas RSA
3. Valide o token assinado do JWT usando chaves públicas RSA
4. Caso queira inverter a ordem de encriptação: Encriptação Chave Privada => Desencriptação Chave Pública para Encriptação Chave Pública => Desencriptação Chave Privada.

1 - Crie chaves públicas e privadas RSA para assinar JWT usando a biblioteca openssl:

```php
// ====================== OPENSSL KEY CREATE METHOD ==================

// URL of the source: https://8gwifi.org/docs/php-asym.jsp
// I tried all 3 types of keys, but only RSA type works.

$password = "password"; // Change it for what value you want

$config = array(  
    "digest_alg" => "sha512",  
    "private_key_bits" => 2048,  
    "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
);  
 
// Create the keypair  
$res = openssl_pkey_new($config);  
// Get private key  
openssl_pkey_export($res, $privkey);  
// Get public key  
$pubkey = openssl_pkey_get_details($res);  
$pubkey = $pubkey["key"];  
  
echo "====PKCS1 RSA Key in Non Encrypted Format ====\n";  
var_dump($privkey);  
echo "====PKCS1 RSA Key in Encrypted Format====\n ";  
  
// Get private key in Encrypted Format  
openssl_pkey_export($res, $privkey,$password);  
// Get public key  
$pubkey = openssl_pkey_get_details($res);  
$pubkey = $pubkey["key"];  
var_dump($privkey);  
echo "RSA Public Key \n ";  
var_dump($pubkey);
```

2 - Criar token JWT e assinar usando chaves privadas RSA e 3 - Validar token assinado JWT usando chaves públicas RSA:

```php
// ====================== JWT WITH ENCRYPT AND DECRYPT ==================

// ===== Variables definition

$keyPrivatePassword = 'password';
$keyPrivatePath = "private.key";
$keyPublicPath = "public.key";
$cryptMaxCharsValue = 245; // There are char limitations on openssl_private_encrypt() and in the url below are explained how define this value based on openssl key format: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-private-encrypt.php#119810

$debug = Array(
    'print-msgs' => true,
    'print-openssl-errors' => false,
    'print-openssl-crypt' => false,
    'print-key-details' => false,
);

// ##################### START DEFINITION OF JWT

// ===== Definition of header

$header = [
   'alg' => 'RSA',
   'typ' => 'JWT'
];

$header = json_encode($header);
$header = base64_encode($header);

// ===== Definition of payload

$payload = [
    'iss' => 'localhost', // The issuer of the token
    'sub' => 'test', // The subject of the token
    'aud' => 'private', // The audience of the token
    'exp' => '1300819380', // This will define the expiration in NumericDate value. The expiration MUST be after the current date/time.
    'data' => [ // Change it with use case data
        'name' => 'User',
        'email' => 'user@mail'
    ]
];

$payload = json_encode($payload);
$payload = base64_encode($payload);

// ===== START ENCRYPT SIGN JWT

$data = $header.".".$payload;

// ===== Print example header

if($debug['print-msgs']){
    echo "JWT CRYPT / DECRYPT EXAMPLE\n\n";
    echo "Value of header . payload: ".$data."\n";
}

// ===== Open private path and return this in string format

$fp = fopen($keyPrivatePath,"r");
$keyPrivateString = fread($fp,8192);
fclose($fp);

// ===== Open private key string and return 'resourse'

if(isset($keyPrivatePassword)){
    $resPrivateKey = openssl_get_privatekey($keyPrivateString,$keyPrivatePassword);
} else {
    $resPrivateKey = openssl_get_privatekey($keyPrivateString);
}

// ===== If any openssl error occurs, print it

$openSSLError = false;
if($debug['print-openssl-errors']){
    while($msg = openssl_error_string()){
        echo $msg . "\n";
        $openSSLError = true;
    }
}

// ===== See details of a private key

if($debug['print-key-details']){
    $keyPrivateDetails = openssl_pkey_get_details($resPrivateKey);

    echo "Private Key Details:\n";
    echo print_r($keyPrivateDetails,true)."\n";
}

// ===== Crypt data in parts if necessary. When char limit of data is upper than 'cryptMaxCharsValue'.

$rawDataSource = $data;

$countCrypt = 0;
$partialData = '';
$encodedData = '';
$split = str_split($rawDataSource , $cryptMaxCharsValue);
foreach($split as $part){
    openssl_private_encrypt($part, $partialData, $resPrivateKey);
    
    if($debug['print-openssl-crypt']){
        $countCrypt++;
        echo "CRYPT PART ".$countCrypt.": ".$partialData."\n";
    }
    
    $encodedData .= (strlen($encodedData) > 0 ? '.':'') . base64_encode($partialData);
}

// ===== If any openssl error occurs, print it

$openSSLError = false;
if($debug['print-openssl-errors']){
    while($msg = openssl_error_string()){
        echo $msg . "\n";
        $openSSLError = true;
    }
}

// ===== Print data encrypted

if($debug['print-msgs']){
    if($openSSLError) echo "\n";

    echo "Encrypted signature: ".$encodedData."\n";
}

// ===== Encode base64 again to remove dots (Dots are used in JWT syntaxe)

$encodedData = base64_encode($encodedData);

if($debug['print-msgs']){
    echo "Encrypted signature Base64: ".$encodedData."\n";
}

$signature = $encodedData;

// ===== FINISH JWT

$JWTToken = $header.".".$payload.".".$signature;

if($debug['print-msgs']){
    echo "\nJWT Token: ".$JWTToken."\n\n";
    echo "FINISH CREATE JWT!\n\n";
}

// ##################### START VALIDATE JWT

$token = $JWTToken;

$part = explode(".",$token);

$header = $part[0];
$payload = $part[1];
$signature = $part[2];

$encodedData = $signature;

// ===== Open public path and return this in string format

$fp = fopen($keyPublicPath,"r");
$chavePublicaString = fread($fp,8192);
fclose($fp);

// ===== Open public key string and return 'resourse'

$resPublicKey = openssl_get_publickey($chavePublicaString);

// ===== If any openssl error occurs, print it

$openSSLError = false;
if($debug['print-openssl-errors']){
    while($msg = openssl_error_string()){
        echo $msg . "\n";
        $openSSLError = true;
    }
}

// ===== See details of a public key

if($debug['print-key-details']){
    $keyPublicDetails = openssl_pkey_get_details($resPublicKey);

    echo "Public Key Details:\n";
    echo print_r($keyPublicDetails,true)."\n";
}

// ===== Decode base64 to reaveal dots (Dots are used in JWT syntaxe)

$encodedData = base64_decode($encodedData);

if($debug['print-msgs']){
    echo "Encrypted signature: ".$encodedData."\n";
}

// ===== Decrypt data in parts if necessary. Using dots as split separator.

$rawEncodedData = $encodedData;

$countCrypt = 0;
$partialDecodedData = '';
$decodedData = '';
$split2 = explode('.',$rawEncodedData);
foreach($split2 as $part2){
    $part2 = base64_decode($part2);
    
    if($debug['print-openssl-crypt']){
        $countCrypt++;
        echo "CRYPT PART ".$countCrypt.": ".$part2."\n";
    }
    
    openssl_public_decrypt($part2, $partialDecodedData, $resPublicKey);
    $decodedData .= $partialDecodedData;
}

// ===== Print data decrypted

if($debug['print-msgs']){
    echo "Decrypted signature: ".$decodedData."\n";
}

// ===== If any openssl error occurs, print it

$openSSLError = false;
if($debug['print-openssl-errors']){
    while($msg = openssl_error_string()){
        echo $msg . "\n";
        $openSSLError = true;
    }
}

// ===== Validate JWT

if($debug['print-msgs']){
    echo "\nFINISH VALIDATE JWT!\n\n";
}

if($header.".".$payload === $decodedData){
    echo "VALID JWT!\n\n";
    
    $payload = base64_decode($payload);
    $payload = json_decode($payload,true);
    
    echo "Payload:\n";
    echo print_r($payload,true);
} else {
    echo "INVALID JWT!";
}
```

4 - Caso queira inverter a ordem de encriptação: Encriptação Chave Privada => Desencriptação Chave Pública para Encriptação Chave Pública => Desencriptação Chave Privada:

```php
// ====================== ENCRYPTATION INVERSE ==================
// If want to change Private Key Encryptation -> Public Key Decryptation to Public Key Encryptation -> Private Key Decryptation this example can help.

$keyPrivatePassword = 'password';
$keyPrivatePath = "private.key";
$keyPublicPath = "public.key";

// ===== Open private path and return this in string format

$fp = fopen($keyPrivatePath,"r");
$keyPrivateString = fread($fp,8192);
fclose($fp);

// ===== Open public path and return this in string format

$fp = fopen($keyPublicPath,"r");
$keyPublicString = fread($fp,8192);
fclose($fp);

// ===== Test of encryptation

$data = 'O que vou encriptar';

$resPrivateKey = openssl_get_privatekey($keyPrivateString,$keyPrivatePassword);
$resPublicKey = openssl_get_publickey($keyPublicString);

echo 'Data: '.$data."\n";

openssl_public_encrypt($data, $encData, $resPublicKey);

echo 'encData: '.$encData."\n";

openssl_private_decrypt($encData, $decData, $resPrivateKey);

echo 'decData: '.$decData."\n";
```